# java - display a report and process results

Tags: java

I need help with `reportSummary()` method located at the end of Survey file. I am building a survey program from scratch using instructions I found online. I am all the way to this point yet I am not sure what I am missing.

Current error(after using help from the answers below):

```
C:\Users\Nael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Survey\src\survey\Survey.java:156: error: illegal start of type
    if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions))
C:\Users\Nael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Survey\src\survey\Survey.java:156: error: not a statement
    if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions))
C:\Users\Nael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Survey\src\survey\Survey.java:156: error: ';' expected
    if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions))
C:\Users\Nael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Survey\src\survey\Survey.java:186: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
4 errors
C:\Users\Nael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Survey\nbproject\build-impl.xml:930: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Nael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Survey\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Survey.java:

```
    package survey;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Survey implements Serializable
{
    private String surveyName;
    private Question[] questions;
    private int numQuestions;
    private int maxResponses;
    private boolean initialized;

    public Survey(String n)
    {
        surveyName = n;
        initialized = false;
    }


        //initialize() sets up the numQuestions, MaxResponses, and questions for the survey

    public char Questions()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Initializing survey \"" + surveyName + "\"\n");

        //add a method for password validation!?!?!?  yes!!!  see the bank accounts lab

        System.out.print("Enter max number of responses: ");
        maxResponses = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of questions: ");
        numQuestions = input.nextInt();

        input.nextLine(); //have to do this to "eat" the new line character or the next input won't work correctly
        System.out.println();

        questions = new Question[numQuestions];
           char choice='c';
        for(int i = 0; i < numQuestions;i++)
        {


        //output menu options
        System.out.println();      
        System.out.println("    S - Create a String Question");
        System.out.println("    N - Create a Integer Question");
        System.out.println("    D - Create a Double Question");


        //loop until a valid input is entered

            System.out.print("Enter choice: ");
            choice = input.next().charAt(0);
            input.nextLine(); //still have to "eat" the current response

            //if choice is one of the options, return it.  Otherwise keep looping
            if( choice == 'N'  )
            {
                 System.out.print("Enter text for question " + (i+1) + ": ");


            //you will also need to ask what KIND of question - right now, defaults to integer question

            questions[i] = new IntegerQuestion(input.nextLine(),maxResponses);
             initialized = true;
            }  

            else if(choice == 'S')
            {
                   System.out.print("Enter text for question " + (i+1) + ": ");

            //you will also need to ask what KIND of question - right now, defaults to integer question

            questions[i] = new TextQuestion(input.nextLine(),maxResponses);
             initialized = true;
            }
             else if(choice == 'D')
            {
                   System.out.print("Enter text for question " + (i+1) + ": ");

            //you will also need to ask what KIND of question - right now, defaults to integer question

            questions[i] = new DoubleQuestions(input.nextDouble(),maxResponses);
             initialized = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.  Ensure a capital letter. Please re-enter.");
                choice = '?';
            }

      }

                         return choice;

    }


    /*
        run() gives the survey to a new survey taker, basically asks all the questions in the survey
    */

    public void startSurvey()
    {
        if(initialized)
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the survey \"" + surveyName + "\"\n");

            for(int i = 0;i < numQuestions; i ++)
            {
                questions[i].askQuestion();
            }

            System.out.println("Thank you for participating!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Survey has not yet been setup.  Please initialize first.");
        }

    }

    /*
        displayResults() displays the raw data for the survey
    */
    public void Results()
    { 
        System.out.println("Displaying data results for \"" + surveyName + "\"\n");

        for(int i = 0;i < numQuestions; i ++)
        {
            questions[i].displayResults();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /*
        displayReportSummary() should run tests on your data 
        Examples could be: the most common response (median), the average response (mean), or display a graph of the results?
        The choices are endless!
    */
    public void reportSummary()
    {
        for(int i=0;< numQuestions; i ++)
        {
            if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions)
                    {
                        DoubleQuestions temp = (DoubleQuestions) questions[i];
                        temp.doubleAverage();
                    System.out.println();
                    }
        }
    }


}
```

DoubleQuestion:

```
package survey;


import java.util.Scanner;


public class DoubleQuestions extends Question 


{
        private double[] responses;


    public DoubleQuestions(double q, int m)
        {
            super(Double.toString(q),(m)); 
            responses = new double[m];
        }

        @Override
        public void askQuestion()
        {
            double response;            
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print(question + " ");
            input.nextLine(); //still have to "eat" the current response          
            response = input.nextDouble(); 
            responses[numResponses] = response;
            numResponses++;
        }

        @Override
        public void displayResults()
        {
            System.out.println(question);
            for(int i = 0; i < numResponses;i++)
                System.out.println(responses[i]);
        }

}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Also, please remove unwanted code and create a [MCVE]

Comment: My question is that in `reportSummary()` my code is not functional.

Comment: not functional means what?

Comment: Do you have any errors with it?

Comment: There is a typo here: `if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions)`. You need to close the if statement condition with a `)`

Comment: @Blasanka I posted the errors

Comment: Just remove this error in your question `error after @anacron's asnwer:`, Tell him in the comment.

Comment: And refer my answer and implement `doubleAverage()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop you have three errors.

One in this line:

```
for(int i=0;< numQuestions; i ++)
```

Here you misswd condition `< numQuestions`

Another one in this line:

```
if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions)
```

Here you missed close bracket `)`.

But

```
if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions))
```

above line should be:

```
if (questions[i] instanceof DoubleQuestions)
```

Fix it:

```
for(int i=0; i < numQuestions; i ++)
{
    if (questions[i] instanceof DoubleQuestions)
            {
                DoubleQuestions temp = (DoubleQuestions) questions[i];
                temp.doubleAverage();
            System.out.println();
            }
}
```

Also your `doubleAverage()` method did not implemented in a `DoubleQuestions` class. So you cannot refer from it.

So you cannot do like this:

```
DoubleQuestions temp = (DoubleQuestions) questions[i];
temp.doubleAverage();
```

First implement the `doubleAverage()`. Then try out.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and understand the error messages that the compiler is throwing at you. It clearly states the line numbers and what error you did in your code.

You need to close the parantheses of your if condition:

```
if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions)
```

must be

```
if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions))
```

---

Your `for` loop has a missing `i` in the condition.

```
    for(int i=0;< numQuestions; i ++)
```

must be :

```
    for(int i=0;i < numQuestions; i ++)
```

---

```
public void reportSummary()
{
    for(int i=0;< numQuestions; i ++)
    {
        if (questions[i] instanceof (DoubleQuestions)) // This line
                {
                    DoubleQuestions temp = (DoubleQuestions) questions[i];
                    temp.doubleAverage();
                System.out.println();
                }
    }
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did fix a typo but it has 7 more errors now, Please check the code again, I updated it and tagged you on the new errors.